# DNS Rebinding attack - will the victim's browser send cookies?

Tags: dns, cookies, dns-rebinding

How does a DNS Rebinding attack work? How can it violate the Same-origin policy?

Will the victim's browser send cookies to the remote server (specified by IP), when the domain is not the same as is in the cookie, created by the same remote server before (keeping the user session)?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/q/14038/2379

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The attacker registers a domain (such as attacker.com) and delegates it to a DNS server he controls. The server is configured to respond with a very short time to live (TTL) record, preventing the response from being cached. When the victim browses to the malicious domain, the attacker's DNS server first responds with the IP address of a server hosting the malicious client-side code.

The malicious client-side code makes additional accesses to the original domain name (such as attacker.com). These are permitted by the same-origin policy. However, when the victim's browser runs the script it makes a new DNS request for the domain, and the attacker replies with a new IP address. For instance, he could reply with an internal IP address or the IP address of a target somewhere else on the Internet."

Simplifying:

1. Victim enter in evil.com
2. evil.com responds with X.X.X.X (IP of malicious server)
3. X.X.X.X loads a malicious script
4. Malicious scripts makes requests to evil.com (same domain)
5. But now evil.com responds with 201.82.108.103 (IP of Google)

Attack done!
The malicious script can now makes requests to Google (pseudo Cross-Site Scripting), because theoretically it is not violating same-origin policy. It is accessing Google, but using evil.com as domain, and it was loaded under evil.com, so the browser can not see any problem with the requests.

Comment: And it will send cookies for google.com?

Comment: no, since the cookies are bound to domain, not IP. However, if Google is vulnerable to session fixation, evil.com could send a cookie with their own session ID in it to Google via the user's browser, and when the user logs in with their credentials, the cookie fron evil.com is set to a logged-in state.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate at all.  No modern browser should be vulnerable to this.  DNS rebinding was patched years ago.

Comment: @Rock Yes, you are right. I just answered how the vulnerability worked and could work in other environments.

Comment: @LucasNN, **How could** DNS Rebinding even work for HTTP 1.1? Those AJAX requests that are trying to bypass sameoriginpolicy are still going to send a header `Host: attacker.com`. And the request would obviously fail because the victim server wouldn't reply anything relevant since it doesn't host any pages for attacker.com...

Comment: @rook, Even without patching, DNS Rebinding wouldn't work for HTTP 1.1 would it? Due to `Host` header, as per the previous comment.

Comment: Many servers ignore Host header, if they don't need it to route traffic.